# Cannot access class property when fetching data in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a class component with a constructor in order to fetch data.

I want to put the data into a class property array and render the data in a dropdown list.

I’m not storing the data as a state as the list of items will not change. But the line, `this.myArray = Object.entries = (obj);`, generates a

> “TypeError: this is undefined” 
>   error.

How can I place the data returned in a class property?

```
class FilterDropdown extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)    
        this.getFormatItems = this.getFormatItems.bind(this)
        this.myArray = []
        this.getFormatItems()
  }

  getFormatItems() {

      var opts = {
          method: 'GET',      
          headers: {}
      };

      fetch(‘http://example-site.com/api/formats’, opts).then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (obj) {

      // TypeError: this is undefined 
      this.myArray = Object.entries = (obj);

    });
  }
```

Comment: You have to bind this in your class constructor function
`this.getFormatItems = this.getFormatItems.bind(this);`

Comment: What is the goal of this line: `this.myArray = Object.entries = (obj)`?

Comment: It converts an object to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in `then` callback function. Use arrow function or use there some previously binded function (like `getFormatItems`).

```
var opts = {
      method: 'GET',      
      headers: {}
  };

  fetch(‘http://example-site.com/api/formats’, opts).then((response) => {
      return response.json();
  })
  .then((obj) => {
  // TypeError: this is undefined 
  this.myArray = Object.entries = (obj);
});
```

Comment: The reason behind it is that arrow functions don't bind their own `this` so instead they use the one from whoever called it, while function does. That is, the `this` would refer to attributes of the function, thus the undefined

Answer (score 0):

use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of traditional declaration and it will automatically bind the function to the class context as below

```
class FilterDropdown extends Component {
    constructor = (props) => {
        super(props)    
        this.getFormatItems = this.getFormatItems.bind(this)
        this.myArray = []
        this.getFormatItems()
    }

    getFormatItems = () => {

      var opts = {
          method: 'GET',      
          headers: {}
      };

      fetch(‘http://example-site.com/api/formats’, opts).then( (response) => {
          return response.json();
      })
      .then((obj) => {

      // TypeError: this is undefined 
      this.myArray = Object.entries = (obj);

    });
}
```

Comment: I get the same result if I switch to an arrow function.

Comment: @AlanP sorry , I missed the arrow function inside then function , that's why it doesn't work